# Can't set the source of the CrReportViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I am trying to display a  crystal report in a WPF window.  The code below works fine for exporting and print the report. its just the last part that I cant get to work. I've tried all 3 lines at the bottom. The `crReportViewer.DataContext` and the `crReportViewer.Content` don't seem to do anything and `crReportViewer.ReportSource` throws the error

'SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.CrystalReportsViewer' does not contain a definition for 'ReportSource' and no extension method 'ReportSource' accepting a first argument of type 'SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.CrystalReportsViewer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
            rptRebateReport cryRpt = new rptRebateReport();
            cryRpt.Load();//error thrown here
            cryRpt.Refresh();
            cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "password", "server", "database");
            cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@SupplierNo", custNumberParam);
            cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@DateFrom", startDateParam);
            cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@DateTo", endDateParam);

            crReportViewer.DataContext = cryRpt;
            crReportViewer.ReportSource = cryRpt;
            crReportViewer.Content = cryRpt;
```

Any help on this error would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the CrystalReportViewer for WPF has a property called "Content". This Content property is literally a StackPanel, with 3 Children, the third being this new element "ViewerCore", which fills all space available on the DockPanel.

The ReportSource property is in this ViewerCore, so to access this ViewerCore (ReadOnly) property, you need to do the following:

```
ViewerCore view = crReportViewer.ViewerCore;
view.ReportSource = cryRpt;
```

Now its working perfectly.